# Superpower: Create parser to Match against "\r\n" or "\n" ( More general: match against a string literal)

Tags: superpower

I want to create a parser for EOL, I can't just do whitespace because I need it to ignore spaces.

So I want to create a parser that will match on "\r\n" or '\n'. Doing a single character is easy `Character.EqualTo('\n')` but trying to match a specific string literal is perplexing me. I would think this should be a regular thing that needs to be done for keywords, but I am at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\r\n` combination is a string, which means that you need to combine the simple `\n` parser (that is a character parser) with a string parser.

How about:

```cs
    public static void Main()
    {
            var crlf = 
                from carriageReturn in Character.EqualTo('\r')
                from lineFeed in Character.EqualTo('\n')
                select new string(carriageReturn, 1) + lineFeed;

            var lf =
                from lineFeed in Character.EqualTo('\n')
                select new string(lineFeed, 1);

            var eol = crlf.Or(lf);
        
        
        eol.TryParse("\r\n").Dump();  // Successful parsing of \r\n
        eol.TryParse("\n").Dump();    // Successful parsing of \n
        eol.TryParse("\r").Dump();    // Syntax error: unexpected end of input, expected line feed.
    }
```

If you prefer the non-LINQ syntax:

```cs
            var eol = Character.EqualTo('\r')
                .Then(carriageReturn => Character.EqualTo('\n').Select( lineFeed => new [] {carriageReturn, lineFeed}))
                .Or(Character.EqualTo('\n').Select(lineFeed => new[] { lineFeed }));
```

Edited: Use the Span parser to parse strings:

```cs
            var eol = Span.EqualTo("\n")
                .Or(Span.EqualTo("\r\n"));
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but what if you want to parse out keywords that are more than 2 characters long? are you still going to have to do it on a per-character basis? There is not shortcut to doing that?

Comment: There probably is. It's been a long time since I used superpower. I'll see what I can dig up.

Comment: And I rediscovered the Span Parser instead. Makes everything nice and neat.

Comment: Thank you. And Yes I prefer method chaining, but finding Superpower docs that use it is hard. So I have reverted to LINQ syntax.